# unable to add parsed JSON to backbone collection

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am trying to parse a multilevel json file, create a model and then add that model to a backbone collection but i can't seem to figure out how to push the model to the collection. This should be a pretty easy problem to solve, i just can't seem to figure it out. Thanks in advance for your help. Below is my model and collection code:

```
var Performer = Backbone.Model.extend({

defaults: {
    name: null,
    top5 : [],
    bottom5 : []
},
initialize: function(){
    console.log("==> NEW Performer");

    // you can add event handlers here...


 }
});

var Performers = Backbone.Collection.extend({

url:'../json_samples/performers.json',
model:Performer,
parse : function(data) {
    // 'data' contains the raw JSON object
    console.log("performer collection - "+data.response.success);

    if(data.response.success)
    {
        _.each(data.result.performers, function(item,key,list){
            console.log("running for "+key);
            var tmpObject = {};
            tmpObject.name = key;
            tmpObject.top5 = item.top5;
            tmpObject.bottom5 = item.bottom5;
            var tmpModel = new Performer(tmpObject);
            this.models.push(tmpModel);
        });

    }
    else
    {
        console.log("Failed to load performers");
    }
}
```

});

Comment: What does `data.result.performers` look like? What do you think `this` is inside the `_.each` callback? Never ever modifying a collection's `models` property, you will leave the collection in an inconsistent state, use the collection's methods to add new models.

Comment: Ditto to what mu said, but also not that the way `parse` needs to work is to take a data structure as an argument and return a different structure as a return value. It should not use `this` at all. In order to fix your `parse` code, we need to see a sample of the `data.result.performers` data because your code is half treating it like an object and half like an array of objects.

Comment: got it, i just used the var that = this trick and that solved the issue. I was trying to push to the models because the normal this.push wasn't working, now i know why. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As has been said in comments to your question, `parse()` is not intended to be used this way. If `data.results.performers` was an `Array`, all you would have to do is returning it. In your case the code will be slightly different.

```
var Performers = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    ...
    parse: function(resp, options) {
        return _.map(resp.result.performers, function(item, key) {
            return _.extend(item, {name: key});
        });
    }
    ...
});
```

On the advice side, if you have the chance to change the API server-side, you'd probably be better off treating collections of objects as arrays and not as objects. Even if it is sometimes convenient to access an object by some ad-hoc key, the data really is an array.

You'll be able to transform it later when you need performers-by-name with a function like underscore's [IndexBy](http://underscorejs.org/#indexBy)